# Gradle - Run Cucumber test

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber, integration-testing

We have the Test runner with the below options

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@DirtiesContext
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = {"path to step defs"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:build/reports/cucumber/cucumber.json",
                "html:build/reports/cucumber/cucumber-report.html"},
        tags = "not @local"
)
public class TestRunner {
}
```

Exception:
TestRunner > executionError FAILED
org.junit.runner.notification.StoppedByUserException at RunNotifier.java:151
2022-05-23 17:55:46.053  INFO 75918 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor           : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

We wrote a scenario outline and when we ran the TestRunner class, the tests got passed. As these tests are added under the test module, we have tried running the ./gradlew test and we got this StoppedByUserException.

Am I missing any configurations?

Comment: could someone help on this?

Comment: Not really. You didn't include the information needed for someone to reproduce the problem and insufficient context to understand what is going on. This `path to step defs` should be a package name, so `com.example` not a path but that's probably not it.

Comment: And maybe start over with https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Comment: M.P.Korstanje path to step defs i just gave here for ref.. i have added the actual path  of the step defitnitions.

Comment: You keep talking about paths. It should be package names. They're different things.